# How to get the zoom level from the leaflet map in R/shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I create a map using leaflet package in Shiny which have a `selectInput` to allow user to select from a site list. The site list also adds into leaflet as markers.

When user selects a new site, I want to recenter map into the selected site without change the zoom level. The `setView` function can be called to set center points, but has to specify the zoom level.

Is it possible to get the zoom level of leaflet map which can be used in the `setView` function?

This is a minimum example to play with my question with reset zoom level.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

df <- data.frame(
    site = c('S1', 'S2'),
    lng = c(140, 120),
    lat = c(-20, -30), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    selectInput('site', 'Site', df$site),
    leafletOutput('map')

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>% 
            setView(lng = 133, lat = -25,  zoom = 4) %>% 
            addMarkers(lng = df$lng, lat = df$lat)
    })

    observe({
        req(input$site)
        sel_site <- df[df$site == input$site,]
        isolate({
            leafletProxy('map') %>%
                setView(lng = sel_site$lng, lat = sel_site$lat, zoom = 4)
        })
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

PS: when you play with these codes, please adjust zoom level before selecting a new site.

Thanks of any suggestions.

Comment: There is an underlying [JavaScript function called `getZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getzoom) that does exactly that, but I'm not quite sure how to access it.

Comment: Thanks. I find it before, but not sure how to add js into shiny and access the value in R code.

Comment: There's `htnlwidgets::JS` or `v8::`,  but I don't know what the leaflet object gets called in the JavaScript or how to get a function evaluated in that same environment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can access the zoom level using `input$mapid_zoom` ([see here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html)).

In your `observe`, you could do:

```
 observe({
                sel_site <- df[df$site == input$site,]
                isolate({
                        new_zoom <- 4
                        if(!is.null(input$map_zoom)) new_zoom <- input$map_zoom
                        leafletProxy('map') %>%
                                setView(lng = sel_site$lng, lat = sel_site$lat, zoom = new_zoom)
                })
        })
```

Comment: Wonderful. I should carefully read leaflet documentation though I already red them many times.