# How to stop reactive in a shiny app in the leaflet map?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, reactive-programming

In my shiny app, I have a `selectInput` `SITE` to list all weather stations and a leaflet map. Following my previous question ([How to get the zoom level from the leaflet map in R/shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985889)), I can `setView` without changing zoom level.

Now I want to add a new feature to allow users to click markers in the map and update the selected values in the `selectInput`. In my current codes (see below for an example), the selected value of `SITE` is updated, but also call the `setView` to change the view point.

My expected features are 1) Selection of new site updates view, 2) Click of map doesn't update view.

How could I break linkage between two features? I guess I can use `isolate` to achieve it. To be honest, I am still confusing about `isolate`.

Thanks for any suggestions.

These are my example codes:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

df <- data.frame(
    site = c('S1', 'S2'),
    lng = c(140, 120),
    lat = c(-20, -30), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    selectInput('site', 'Site', df$site),
    leafletOutput('map')

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>% 
            setView(lng = 133, lat = -25,  zoom = 4) %>% 
            addMarkers(lng = df$lng, lat = df$lat, popup = df$site)
    })


    observe({
        sel_site <- df[df$site == input$site,]
        isolate({
            new_zoom <- 4
            if (!is.null(input$map_zoom)) new_zoom <- input$map_zoom
            leafletProxy('map') %>%
                setView(lng = sel_site$lng, lat = sel_site$lat, zoom = new_zoom)
        })
    })

    observe({
        event <- input$map_marker_click

        if (is.null(event))
            return()
        click_site <- df %>% 
            filter(lng == event$lng, lat == event$lat)
        isolate({
            updateSelectInput(session, 'site', selected = click_site$site)
        })
    })


})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Where did you find the documentation referencing `input$map_zoom`?  I have a somewhat related question located [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468752/flexdashboards-and-leaflet-reactivity) that I am trying to get to the bottom of.

Comment: I am not entirely clear on the question, but we are building `mapedit` to help address some of these goals.  Please see post http://r-spatial.org/r/2017/01/30/mapedit_intro.html.  We'd love feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked for, because it uses a button, but maybe you can make a good use of it. I also fixed your filtering.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

df <- data.frame(
  site = c('S1', 'S2'),
  lng = c(140, 120),
  lat = c(-20, -30), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput('site', 'Site', df$site),
  actionButton("center","Center map on site"),
  leafletOutput('map')

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = 133, lat = -25,  zoom = 4) %>% 
      addMarkers(lng = df$lng, lat = df$lat, popup = df$site)
  })
observeEvent(input$center,{
    sel_site <- df[df$site == input$site,]
    isolate({
      new_zoom <- 4
      if (!is.null(input$map_zoom)) new_zoom <- input$map_zoom
      leafletProxy('map') %>%
        setView(lng = sel_site$lng, lat = sel_site$lat, zoom = new_zoom)
    })
  })

  observe({
    event <- input$map_marker_click

    if (is.null(event))
      return()
    else{
    latdist<- unlist(lapply((event$lat - df$lat), FUN=abs))

      if (min(latdist)<4){ 
      match <- 
        df[with(df, {which(lat[latdist==min(latdist)] == lat ) 
      }), ]
      if(abs(match$lng-event$lng)<4)
      {
        click_site <- df[with(df,{ which(lng == match$lng & lat == match$lat) }),]  
      }
      updateSelectInput(session, 'site', selected = click_site$site)

     }# first if
    } # end else
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```