# How to Access the Zoom and Position settings of Synchronized Maps in Leaflet in an R Shiny Web Page

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I'm building an R Shiny web page that displays synchronized maps. The number of maps displayed changes, based on user-set filtering criteria. The maps are built on-the-fly as leaflets and displayed with sync() in a dynamic UI panel.

I want the position and zoom level of the maps to remain the same when the user makes new selections. I think I could do that by saving and re-applying the zoom and position values from the current state of the map, but I can't figure out how to get those values when they're wrapped in a sync() inside a rendered UI.

Here's a simplified, runnable example of what I've got so far.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leafsync)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Display N Maps"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("mapCount",
                        "Number of maps:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 4,
                        value = 2)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("tiledMaps")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    map.rv <- reactiveValues()
    map.rv$count <- 0
    map.rv$zoom <- 9
    map.rv$ctrLng <- 174.768
    map.rv$ctrLat <- -36.852
    
    tileMap <- function(i) {
        leaflet(paste0("map",i)) %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            setView(lng = map.rv$ctrLng,
                    lat = map.rv$ctrLat,
                    zoom = map.rv$zoom)
    }

    output$tiledMaps <- renderUI({
        print(input$map1_zoom)
        mapArray <- apply(as.array(1:input$mapCount), 1, 
                          function(i){tileMap(i)})
        sync(mapArray)
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The `input$map1_zoom` is an attempt to apply the advice given in answer to this question [How to get the zoom level from the leaflet map in R/shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985889/how-to-get-the-zoom-level-from-the-leaflet-map-in-r-shiny) but the value always comes up NULL.

Is there a way to access the position and zoom level I'm looking for? Better yet, maybe I've taken an unnecessarily complex approach to solving my problem, and someone will offer a better, cleaner, simpler way to create and display my maps.